# Update Primary Key by updating foreign key

Tags: mysql

I have a Member table as follows:

Member Table:

```
 Name              |          Handicap
 Joe Bloggs        |             18
```

Stableford Table:

```
  Player_name    |     Player Handicap    |   Score   |   Handicap Change
    Joe Bloggs   |            18          |     38    |         17
```

I now want to update the Player Handicap with the Handicap Change value (17) but I get an error:

> cannot update a child row.

`Player Handicap` is a FOREIGN KEY in the `Stableford` table. It `REFERENCES member(handicap)`.

When I update the `Player Handicap` field in `Stableford` table I also want the handicap field in my member table to be updated. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you allowed to change the FK definition?

Comment: Yes I will be able change the FK definition

Comment: I removed my answer because I had misread the question (sorry for that). What exactly are you trying to accomplish? You're clearly not using foreign keys for the traditional purpose of the tool (enforce data integrity). If you want to denormalise your data so you don't have to use table joins and you thought foreign keys would sync data for you, I have to say that's not possible. Just use relational databases as intented and *join* tables as much as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to do this at all.

What you have here is a classic denormalization.

It doesn't make any sense whatsoever to have Handicap as a foreign key. It only makes sense to have the player himself as a foreign key.

You need to *get rid of* the Handicap field from the Stableford table, and get it from the Member table via the member's *name* as a foreign key, via a join, when necessary.

You do *not* want to repeat any attribute of a Member other than his key in any other table.